# Checking for a file using htaccess using a string of conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following to pass details of a potential file location on the server, but line 3 causes it to fail. By removing this line, the test.php file sees the correct file location built up by the %1/%2

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)\.domain\.com?
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (images/.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%1 ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)\.domain\.com(images/.*)
RewriteCond %1/%2 -f
RewriteRule ^.* test.php?file=%1/%2 [L]
```

Once it's working I'll serve the file if it exists from the new location, if not the next rewrite function will built the image and put it in the location for next time.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've worked out the problem, and to save someone days of headaches here is the solution.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{THE_REQUEST} ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)\.domain\.com.*?(/images[^\s]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%2 -f
RewriteRule ^.* %1%2 [L]
```

The file check required the document root, I've spend days trying to work this out.
The final result is that files that exist are served straight through, if they don't another rewrite after the above can pick up the request and place the file in the correct location.
Thanks for your help David Ravetti, you can now hopefully understand what I was after.

Comment: Glad you found a working solution. If you need to additional work on it in the future, you might want to experiment with `RewriteBase` to see if it could help simplify the rules. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking some necessary details, but here's a guess at what's going on.

If the request is for `http://abc123.domain.com/whatever/images/somefile.jpg`, then:

RewriteCond 1 matches and `%1` = "abc123".

RewriteCond 2 then matches and `%2` = "images/somefile.jpg".

RewriteCond 3 makes no sense at all as you're trying to match "abc123.domain.comabc123" to "(something).domain.comimages/.*".

RewriteCond 4 tries to ensure that "abc123/images/somefile.jpg" exists as a real file.

So, I'm guessing that your directory structure is "/domainprefix/images" so with the URL above you're trying to make sure that the image exists at "/abc123/images/somefile.jpg". If this is the case, then RewriteCond 3 and 4 should be modified as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /%1/%2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

Again, I'm having to guess at exactly what your goal is, but this should be at least closer to what you need.

Comment: You're spot on with the goal.
The existing Condition 3 matches HOST + %1 which equates to http://abc123.domain.comimages/somefile.jpg and is nothing more than a way of getting both of the parts needed for the file check in Condition 4
The first Condition is only there to filter out this set of conditions over others in the htaccess file.
I'll try your suggestion and let you know it's outcome.

Comment: Alas, no luck! But you have made me rethink the checks needed, this is a shortened version, but the file check still isn't passing though!
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{THE_REQUEST} ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)\.domain\.com(images/.*)?
RewriteCond %1/%2 -f
RewriteRule ^.* test.php?file=%1/%2 [L]`

Comment: I'm a step closer with this one, but the file check fails!
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{THE_REQUEST} ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)\.domain\.com.*?(/images[^\s]+)`

`RewriteRule ^.* test.php?file=%1%2 [L]`

The original using REQUEST_URI and THE_REQUEST weren't fully matching the images name. This version shows the correct filename, now I need to add in the file check... 1 line and it no-longer works!
`RewriteCond %1/%2 -f` with or without the slash!

Comment: Can you spell out the exact format of the string you want to pass to `test.php?file=`? Based on your comments above, I think you're confusing how `%1`, `%2`, etc. work. These expressions only match what is in parentheses in the RewriteConds, in sequential order starting from the first RewriteCond.

Comment: Using the latest version, the first Condition gathers the sub-domain and the image filename. Then going straight to the Rule at this stage outputs abc123/images/somefile.jpg in the test file from abc123.domain.com/images/somefile.jpg . But adding the second Condition in as `RewriteCond %1%2 -f` fails as a condition and therefore it never makes it to the test file, despite the file existing on the server.